# Jboss eap 6.4 https configuration is failing to listen to the port 8443

Tags: java, jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-6

I am using jboss-eap-6.4 to deploy my web application.I want to make my server supports https requests. So I have generated keystore using the following command:

```
 keytool -genkey -v -keystore foo.keystore -alias foo
```

I moved the above keystore file under `D:\\jboss-eap-6.4\\standalone\\configuration\\` and added the following connector in `standalone.xml` file:

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
                <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
                <connector name="https" socket-binding="https" scheme="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" secure="true" enable-lookups="false">
                <ssl name="foo-ssl" protocol="TLSv1" certificate-key-file="D:\\jboss-eap-6.4\\standalone\\configuration\\foo.keystore" key-alias="foo" password="secret"/>
                </connector>
                <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                    <alias name="localhost"/>
                    <alias name="example.com"/>
                </virtual-server>
 </subsystem>
```

https port is configured to the port 8443:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

Then I tried to access the url using the port number 8443(via https), but the the application is failing to listen to the port. Any idea what I am missing here?

The error details:
In IE Edge:

```
Can’t connect securely to this page
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Your TLS security settings aren’t set to the defaults, which could also be causing this error.
Try this:
Go back to the last page
```

In firefox:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to hddt0719:8443. Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). Error code: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Learn more…

Report errors like this to help Mozilla identify and block malicious sites
```

Comment: is the socket-binding defined in the <socket-binding-group>, e.g. <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>?
also, do you start your jboss with a port-offset? if so, try calling the url with the adapted port-offset.

Comment: @meaningqo, I have added `<socket-binding-group>` to the question now, please take a look. port-offset is zero in my case.  Any ideas now?

Comment: what do you mean by 'application is failing to listen to the port' ? what error are you getting.

Comment: @Abhijeet, Added the error details to the question now, please take a look. Any ideas now?

Comment: According to error logs, you have not specified cyphers for your ssl tag. add `cipher-suite`  to solve the issue

Comment: `/profile=default/subsystem=web/connector=HTTPS/ssl=configuration/:write-attribute(name=protocol,value=TLSv1)` use this to add TLS protocol

Comment: @Abhijeet, I have added `cipher-suite="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"` in standalone.xml file for the `<connector>`, but still the same issue. Any other idea please? or is my `cipher-suite` value wrong?

Comment: I think @Abhijeet has grasped the problem correctly. 
also you should probably consider using a newer version of tls instead of v1 which you set here: `protocol="TLSv1"`
as it will no longer be supported by march 2020 by sadfari, firefox, edge and chrome according to https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/05/tls-1-0-and-1-1-removal-update/

Comment: @Ashok.N use TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 protocols instead of TLSv1 as suggested by meaningqo

Comment: @Abhijeet, Tried with TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2, but no use. Any other idea?

Comment: i have looked a bit trought the jboss documentation. are you using openssl or jsse? according to the documentation that makes a difference in how you define your cypher suites: `For JSSE syntax, it must be a comma-separated list.For OpenSSL syntax, it must be a colon-separated list. Ensure that only one syntax is used.` 

list of openssl ciphers: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER-STRINGS

list of jsse cyphers: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/ciphers.html

edit: corrected openssl cipher link

Comment: source: 
source: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/pdf/how_to_configure_server_security/Red_Hat_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-6.4-How_To_Configure_Server_Security-en-US.pdf

Comment: @meaningqo how to know whether the server is using `openssl` or `JSSE`?

Comment: @Ashok.N Try to use protocol="TLSv1.2" only remove 1.1 and restart server and browser

Comment: @Abhijeet, Tried with protocol="TLSv1.2", but no use. do I need to change any other file?

Comment: @Ashok.N No other files needs any changes. I think issue is with your trust sore. Add keyalg as RSA (which is supported widely) e.g. -keyalg RSA

Comment: also try adding some additional ciphersuites. i have found this list as widely supported, so it might be a good starting point. 

ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

unfortunately i dont know how to find out if you are using openssl or jsse, so maybe try the list with : as well as comma-separated

Comment: @Ashok.N are you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way, the keystore is generated, use command

```
 keytool -genkey -keystore foo.keystore -alias foo -keyalg "RSA" -sigalg "SHA1withRSA" -keysize 2048 -validity 365
```

By default keytool generates DSA type keystore, you should provide RSA type keystore.
I checked keys of both types, my jBoss worked with RSA ssl keystore generated in proposed way.
Your jBoss configuration is correct.